# Angular async validation of existing emails

Tags: angular

I have a problem with validating existing email; the validation works, but when I rewrite mails, it does not go out of error state.

Validation form

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.frm = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.UsedEmails.bind(this)]),
        });
    }
```

Checking for existing emails

```
UsedEmails(control: FormControl): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.usersService.getAdminByEmail(control.value)
                .subscribe(
                    (user: User[]) => {
                        if (user.length) {
                            // does not change state when changing email, always stays in 
                            // resolve({forbidenEmail: true});
                            console.log("Err!");
                            resolve({
                                forbidenEmail: true
                            });
                        } else {
                            // do not reach
                            console.log("Ok!");
                            resolve(null);
                        }
                    }
                );
        });
    }
```

usersService

```
 constructor(
            private http: BaseApi,
        ) { 
    getAdminByEmail(email: string): Observable<User[]> {
            return this.http.get(`auth?email=${email}`);
        }
```

html form

```
<form [formGroup]="frm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input 
                matInput 
                placeholder="Enter your email" 
                formControlName="email"
                required
                (keyup)="OnKeyUpEm($event)"
            >
            <mat-error *ngIf="checkControl('email')">{{getErrMes("email")}}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <hr>
        <button type="submit" id="registBut" mat-raised-button [disabled]="frm.invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake here:

```
email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.UsedEmails.bind(this)])
```

Your provide sync validators and the async validator in one array. But async validators must be used as third parameter in FormControl:

```
 email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.UsedEmails.bind(this))
```

I also recommend to use observables instead of a promise and also to use the formBuilder. For example:

```
 constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: [
        '',
        [Validators.required, Validators.email],
        this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)
      ]
    });
  }




  validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl): Observable {
          // check if email exists
  }
```